Wittgenstein on sense
What's sense according to Wittgenstein?
I think I might have missed the definition in TLP, but I can't find it anywhere.
From the context it's obvious that Wittgenstein's sense isn't that of Frege. But it's still not very clear.
Are the 'sense' and the 'truth-value' synonymous in TLP? Does the presence of sense in a proposition just means that we can determine its truth-value?
P.S. The whole question is about Tractatus logical-philosophicus (was already mentioned here as TLP).

See Making 'sense' of Wittgenstein's senselessness / nonsense distinction in the Tractatus

Wittgenstein only uses "sense" as nominalization in TLP, it is not a thing. He does say what sensible propositions are, those that conform to the logical form and have referents in reality, "pictures of reality" as he puts it. Essentially, those are propositions of natural science only. Even propositions of logic and mathematics are "senseless" by his definition, they do not "picture" reality but pertain to form only. And then there are non-sensical propositions beyond "limits of thinking" (metaphysics). See SEP, Sense and Nonsense

Sinn is "semantic content", more or less like in Frege: the difference is that sinn for Frege is a thought (something grasped in thinking) while for W it is a representation.
See 2.221: What a picture represents is its sense.
And see also 4.031: Instead of, ‘This proposition has such and such a sense’, we can simply say, ‘This proposition represents such and such a situation’.
Thus, it is not the truth value of a statement.
For a good discussion of the relationship between tractarian views and Frege and Russell's theories, see Michael Morris, Wittgenstein and the Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus (Routledge, 2008).
